# Can you change a punctuation mark when referencing a passage from a text?

Tags: citations, essay, punctuation, mla

I'm writing an essay for the play *Waiting for Godot,* and there is a passage I want to use:

> ESTRAGON: (*very insidious*). But what about Saturday? And is it Saturday? Is it not rather Sunday? (Pause.) Or Monday? (Pause.) Or Friday?

To express the dislocation of time in the play, I want to quote the passage starting from 'Saturday;' but I don't know whether I'm allowed to replace the question marks with commas, as that would make the passage fit with my sentence.

I want to try to avoid quoting only the days with commas, because it feels detached and somewhat useless to reference each day with a separate quote, like "Monday" and "Tuesday" and "Wednesday," at least to me.

Am I allowed to change question mark punctuation when referencing MLA, or must I find another way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Citing the [GCMS High School Media Center](http://www.gcms.k12.il.us/gcmshs/hslibrary/new_page_1.htm) (highlighted by me)

> Changes **must not** be made in the spelling, capitalization, or **punctuation** of the quote.

So it looks like you have to find another way.

Comment: You would do better to quote in full, and then paraphrase if you need to bring out a specific interpretation. Then again, you might be able to use "to paraphrase Estragon ....", making it clear that you are reworking the passage.